# Groovy/Grails cannot load oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy

I am trying to test a grails app connecting to a sql server, for now, I am using one of my own. This is my datasource.groovy

```
    dataSource {
        configClass = GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.class
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/xe"
        username = "blah"
        password = "blah"
        properties {
            validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
            testWhileIdle=true
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
        }
    }
```

I have borrowed this code from a different app, just changing the url and user/password.  The other app runs fine, but my app throws a long exception, which boils down to this

```
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
stack trace
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I have copied ojdbc6.jar into my app lib/ but I am afraid I am lost on what to do next.

**EDIT** I have updated `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` to `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, but no progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, turns out the problem was what @tim_yates suggested.  The problem that I had since then was that even though I was refreshing the dependencies, as @burt said, but I had never re-loaded the config files.

I just ran `grails clean` then `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` and voila, problem solved. Thanks to @burt and @tim_yates for helping me out

Comment: In my experience, "grails clean" does not delete *.class files in grails-app/conf created from DataSource.groovy and BuildConfig.groovy. I have no idea, by the way, at which point they were created. But deleting those files and/or recompiling them with groovyc helps!

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

when you add a jar to the lib directory so Grails adds it to the classpath. This is a new requirement in 2.0+

Unrelated - you can remove

```
configClass = GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.class
```

since that's the default now

Comment: Did as you said, unfortunately, app will still not run, same errors

Comment: I take that back, it is breaking, but the location is unknown and all information I have is that it is a java exception breakpoint

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't the class be:

```
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

I believe the other one was deprecated

Comment: I have seen the other one work, but if I change it i get the same error with ClassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver