# Grails cannot load oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and --refresh-dependencies does not work

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I get **ClassNotFoundException**: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` any time I do a grails run-app without having done --refresh-dependencies immediately prior (I have the oracle driver .jar in my project /lib).

I have seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314664/groovy-grails-cannot-load-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver) and elsewhere, and the answer always seems to be to run --refresh-depdencies

However, I find that doing this only works for exactly one time after --refresh-dependencies is run. Any subsequent time I do run-app I get the **ClassNotFoundException**: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` again, until I once again run --refresh-dependencies. By running --refresh-dependencies every time I am about to run-app I can still function, but it is quite annoying.

I am running grails 2.3.0.

grails output without having done --refresh-dependencies immediately prior to run-app:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security LDAP ...
... finished configuring Spring Security LDAP
Configuring Spring Security CAS ...
... finished configuring Spring Security CAS
| Error 2014-01-14 15:15:14,235 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
->>  175 | findClass in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    423 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    147 | loadClass in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    356 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    266 | forName . in java.lang.Class
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker

^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

and right after doing --refresh-dependencies:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security LDAP ...
... finished configuring Spring Security LDAP
Configuring Spring Security CAS ...
... finished configuring Spring Security CAS
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/loggity-rest
```

Comment: Try upgrading to 2.3.4 or at least something other than 2.3.0 - there are lots of bugs fixed in between the two releases

Comment: I upgraded to 2.3.4 and am still experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do not consider this to be an "answer" to my own question, but I am posting it here as a possible workaround solution in case anyone else is experiencing this issue.

I was able to get this problem to stop happening by pulling my oracle driver in through BuildConfig.groovy rather than using the /lib folder.

The reason I do not consider this a solution is that in order to do this you need a repository  where the oracle driver artifact can be found, and it is not in any public repositories nor allowed to be due to "stinginess" on the part of oracle.

My company has a private repository that I am able to use that is shared by our CI server, and this solution would work only for those that have access to a private repository of some kind. What I put into my BuildConfig.groovy is pretty much what you might expect:

```
runtime "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
```

Those that cannot use this solution due to not having a repository available with the oracle driver jar in it will still need a solution to the issue that arises when using /lib.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problem where one time it would run app fine but as soon as I restart it will throw "pool connection" exception.

Adding the following line in BuildConfig.groovy fixed my problem. Not sure why it was missing to begin with.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the new Aether dependency manager that's used by default in 2.3. It's a lot faster than and in general works better than Ivy, but there are a handful of Ivy features that aren't supported.

I was able to get this working by changing from Aether to Ivy in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this resulted in no change for me.

Comment: Try running `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: I am already doing that, as doing so is part of replicating the problem. As before, when running grails compile --refresh-dependencies the issue does not appear when run-app is run immediately after, but any subsequent time that run-app is run the issue appears unless grails compile --refresh-dependencies is run again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line in my `BuildConfig` from this:

```
runtime "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
```

to this (leaving out com.):

```
runtime "oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
```

worked for me.